# Ошибка Could not install Gradle distribution

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx-coroutines

**Установил зависимости в build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
}
```

**Импортировал корутины в main**

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
```

**GlobalScope и delay не работают**

```
fun main() {
    GlobalScope.launch { 
        delay(1000L) 
        println("World!") 
    }
    println("Hello,") 
    Thread.sleep(2000L) 
}
```

Выдается ошибка:

> Could not install Gradle distribution from 'services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'

Comment: Ваш код работает корректно. Уточните [прямо в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1475170/edit), в чем именно выражается "GlobalScope и delay не работают". Что конкретно происходит при запуске программы?

Comment: выдается ошибка: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.1-all.zip'

Comment: Проблема не в GlobalScope или delay, а в том, что не устанавливается система сборки Gradle. Переформулируйте вопрос и [добавьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1475170/edit) все необходимые детали (подробную информацию об ошибке).

Comment: На дворе 2022 год и gradle [версии 7.6](https://gradle.org/releases/). Возможно, IDE не хочет иметь дела с gradle восьмилетней давности. Версия 2.1 была выпущена в 2014 году.